# How do I use rysnc to copy my entire Google Drive to an external hard drive?

Tags: rsync, google-drive, chromebook

I am trying to copy my entire Google drive contents to an external hard drive.

1. I am using rsync with the built in Linux environment on my Chromebook.
2. I do not want to install a third party app on Linux. Also, I have Google advanced security turned on with a yubikey if that matters.

I first shared Google drive folder with Linux in the files app on my Chromebook.

Then shared my external using the files app on my Chromebook.

I then tried:

```
rsync -a /source/* /destination
```

Seems to be working but multiple error messages. Seems like none of the Google Doc or Google Sheet files are copying over.

Should I instead use:

```
rsync -aH /source/* /destination
```

Or this?

```
rsync -aL /source/* /destination`
```

Comment: Good question! ProTip™: Use the `--dry-run` option with Rsync to see what Rsync would copy over without actually doing any copying. Excellent option of debugging. Like this is your first command with the dry run option set: `rsync -a --dry-run /source/* /destination`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I stopped the current rsync operation and tried the above. I initially did not get anything output. I then added a -v and saw that the files in question were supposed to be copied. Not sure what to make of it when the --dry-run shows it should be copied but it actually gave and error when copying.

I guess I will have to try with the -H and/or -L switch if no one else has any ideas.